# Fading images in and out, interval is messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fading images in and out at random for a certain div.

Here is the div html code:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" />
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg" />
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$('.container img:gt(0)').hide();

$(function () {

    var className = ".container";
    var suffix = " :first-child";
    var path = className.concat(suffix);
    setInterval(function () {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#container").children().length);
        console.log($("#container").children().length);
        console.log(randomnumber);
        // Fade out the first element and fade in the next and then move the elements

        jQuery(path).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $("#container > img:eq(" + randomnumber + ")").fadeIn(1000);
            jQuery(className).append($(this).clone());

            jQuery(this).remove();
        });
    },
    3000);
});
```

It essentially works, but I have it fading every 3000 milliseconds and the new images starts to fade in when the current image fades out.

But sometimes the intervals are off: it doesn't start fading at 3 seconds or it stays on a blank white screen for some reason. I'm not sure why it does this. Any ideas?

If you look at the jsfiddle for a minute you will see it isn't consistent: http://jsfiddle.net/x300a41n/18/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've used some CSS with some new JS to reach a random slider, do you think it's good?

http://jsfiddle.net/x300a41n/19/

```
$(function () {

    var nImages = $("#container").children().length;
    var currentImage = 1;

    setInterval(function () {

        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nImages);
        randomnumber -= 1;

        if ( currentImage == randomnumber )
            randomnumber = ( randomnumber < nImages ) ? randomnumber + 1 : 0;

        currentImage = randomnumber;
        $('#container img').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#container > img:eq('+randomnumber+')').fadeIn(1000);

    },3000);


});
```

Comment: This is solid. Thanks. How can I make it start with an image rather than a black screen?

Comment: Incidentally, @Harry, it looks like the cause of the original code rendering a blank was that randomnumber occasionally returned 0.

Comment: @PeteScott was right. One of the problems is that the eq:() selector of jQuery start from 0, so if you get a random number from 0 to 3 (nums of img), there will be a '3' value as index, and 3 values as index not match any image in div#container.

Comment: one last question: am I able to make the div containing the images fit the content of the images? Instead of making it a set height of 322px ?

Comment: @Monte thanks again for the help, really appreciate it. I have another question regarding this topic in another sense, so if you want you can help me out again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246798/fading-in-out-of-images-expands-grid-view-of-images-surrounding-it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container img').hide();
var myFadeIn = function () {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#container").children().length);
    $("#container > img:eq(" + randomnumber + ")")
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(1000, myFadeIn);
};
myFadeIn();
```

This code will work for a named function (called by recursion) for FadeIn/FadeOut.