# Fading in/out of images expands grid-view of images surrounding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a grid of images and I'm planning on having them all fade random images in and out. I have the fading fine when it **isn't** in a grid using inline-block.

But when I fade images in, the image that is fading in appears below the one fading out. What I want is the one fading in to be **behind** the one fading out, so there is a smooth transition. The easiest way to see what I mean is this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/67/

Any ideas? Thanks

```
<body>
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="fadein">
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%">
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg" style="width:100%" ">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg " style="width:100% "">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

$(function () {

    var nImages = $(".fadein").children().length;
    var currentImage = 0;
    console.log(nImages);

    setInterval(function () {

        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nImages);
        randomnumber -= 1;

        if (currentImage == randomnumber) randomnumber = (randomnumber < nImages) ? randomnumber + 1 : 0;

        currentImage = randomnumber;
        $('.fadein img').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.fadein > img:eq(' + randomnumber + ')').fadeIn(1000);

    }, 3000);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn off the javascript you get an idea of where your problem arises, the images are stacked vertically. To get what you want use `position:relative` for the containing div and `position:absolute` to get the images to collapse onto each other, then use `z-index` to get the first image to appear first. The one issue is the image height musf be fixed an known, as you also need to set this on the containig div (or you could use jquery, see update)

CSS:

```
#grid {
 width: 500px;
}
#grid div {
    display: inline-block;
    width:30%;
    margin: 0.5em .4em;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
}

.fadein img
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.fadein img:first-child
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}


img {
    width: 100%;   
}

.fadeSpot1 {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
    position:relative;
}

.fadeSpot1 img {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/69/)

**Update**

As you are already using jquery, you could use that to set the height of the parent div

```
$('.fadein').css('height', $('.fadein img:first-child').css('height'));
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/70/)

Comment: Looks good. Plus the jQuery code is solid. Luckily I do know the image heights anyway. Thanks for the help!